# Getting the difference of quantity between 2 different django model fields?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have here 2 django database table

```
class Inventory(models.Model):
     product_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
     qty = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Order(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Inventory, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
     qty = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I would like to have an inventory table page wherein I can see the total qty left in Inventory (for example: Inventory.qty - Order.qty) .

how to do this in Django ?

Answer (score 2):

You can annotate the `Inventory` with the `qty` minus the sum of the related `Order`s:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Inventory.objects.annotate(
    qty_left=F('qty') - Sum('order__qty')
)
```

The `Inventory` objects that arise from *this* `QuerySet` will have an extra attribute `.qty_left` that contains the `qty` of the `Inventory` minus the sum of the `qty`s of the *related* `Order`s.

Comment: Am I going to do this on Django models or in views.py ?

Comment: @Bwakarot41: in the view where you render the `Inventory`s with the corresponding quantity left.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Will going to try this now.

Comment: Hello sir. How am i going to use this in Django template?

Comment: @Bwakarot41: as said, the objects have an extra attribute, so if you iterate over the `Inventory` objects, you can render it with `{{ inventory.qty_left }}`.

Comment: Hi sir. I'm done doing that. But instead of showing the ```product_name```, it show only the id of product name. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Bwakarot41: you show the product name with `{{ inventory.product_name }}`.